# Unable to render .MSG files via "https://view.officeapps.live.com/op/embed.aspx?src=[MSG file URL]" on HTML iframe

Tags: html, iframe, office365, ms-office

I have to render some office files( .doc, .ppt, .xls, .msg, .eml)  which are publicly accessible documents on the browser.

I was using iframe like below and it rendered all the documents except the mail files(.msg and .eml)

**Below 3 are working:- (.doc, .xls,.ppt):-**

```
<iframe src='https://view.officeapps.live.com/op/embed.aspx?src=https://file-examples-com.github.io/uploads/2017/02/file-sample_100kB.doc' width='100%' height='500vh' frameborder='0'></iframe>

<iframe src='https://view.officeapps.live.com/op/embed.aspx?src=https://file-examples-com.github.io/uploads/2017/02/file_example_XLS_10.xls' width='100%' height='500vh' frameborder='0'></iframe> 

<iframe src='https://view.officeapps.live.com/op/embed.aspx?src=https://file-examples-com.github.io/uploads/2017/08/file_example_PPT_1MB.ppt' width='100%' height='500vh' frameborder='0'></iframe>
```

**.msg is not working:- ( below is not working) - giving error as file not found( but this is a public URL)**

```
 <iframe src='https://view.officeapps.live.com/op/embed.aspx?src=https://github.com/bbottema/outlook-message-parser/raw/master/src/test/resources/test-messages/S_MIME%20test%20message%20encrypted.msg' width='100%' height='500vh' frameborder='0'></iframe>
```

Please Help me in this scenario???